# Output sorted python dict within django template

Tags: python, django, templates, sorting, dictionary

I got a python dict, that looks like the following (Important informations were replaced with "xxx" due to privacy reasons).
I would like to display this dict within a django template but it should be ordered, so it should start with "A", then continue with "B" instead of "H"

This is my dict (shortened):

```
{   'A': [   {'birthday_date': None,
             'first_name': 'Alberto',
             'last_name': 'xxx',
             'name': 'Alberto xxx',
             'uid': xxx},
         {   'birthday_date': None,
             'first_name': 'Antony',
             'last_name': 'xxx',
             'name': 'Antony xxx',
             'uid': xxx}],
'H': [   {   'birthday_date': '08/28',
             'first_name': 'Hitoshi',
             'last_name': 'xxx',
             'name': 'Hitoshi xxx',
             'uid': xxx}],
'C': [   {   'birthday_date': '05/07/1985',
             'first_name': 'Chr',
             'last_name': 'xxx',
             'name': 'Chr xxx',
             'uid': xxx}],
'E': [   {   'birthday_date': None,
             'first_name': 'Edimond',
             'last_name': 'xxx',
             'name': 'Edimond xxx',
             'uid': xxx},
         {   'birthday_date': '08/30',
             'first_name': 'Erika',
             'last_name': 'xxx',
             'name': 'Erika xxx',
             'uid': xxx}],
'B': [   {   'birthday_date': '08/16/1987',
             'first_name': 'Bhaktin',
             'last_name': 'xxx',
             'name': 'Bhaktin xxx',
             'uid': xxx}],
'I': [   {   'birthday_date': '08/25/1987',
             'first_name': 'Ivette',
             'last_name': 'xxx',
             'name': 'Ivette xxx',
             'uid': xxx}]}
```

This is my django template:

```
{% for letter, friend in bdays_all.items %}
    <h2>{{ letter }}</h2>
    {% for user in friend %}
         ...
    {% endfor %}
{% endfor %}
```

This works well, but its not ordered. But thats what I need. I tried everything with python's sorted() function but without any successs. I only want to order the letters. Seems trivial but I guess it isn't.

Any ideas?

Thanks alot in advance!

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Dictionaries are unsorted.

You will need to convert your dict to a nested list in the view: the easiest way would be just to call `sorted(bdays_all.items())`.

Comment: Ah, I didn't know that. Thanks alot for your answer, I will acceppt it as soon as I am able to do so. (5 mins)

Answer (score 0):

You also could create a new dictionary with sorted keys in your view:

```
dictio = {'a': 'orange', 'c':'apple', 'b': 'bannana'}
di = {}
for key in sorted(dictio.iterkeys()):
    di[key] = dictio[key]
```

whit the result:

```
di = {'a': 'orange', 'b': 'bannana', 'c': 'apple'}
```

Comment: Dictionaries are hashes under the hood, so key order is never guaranteed. That's why OrderedDict exists.